# While loops Depreciation (Help)

Tags: java

I am attempting to create a program that will output the value at the beginning of the year, the amount depreciated during year, and the total amount of overall depreciation for each year given in that life span. For example, if I bought an item in 2005 and its life span was 5 years, it would calculate the depreciation for that item for those 5 years.

I wasn't very sure where to start with this project and this is what I have so far. However, at this point I am stuck and now I am unsure of what to do next.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ConnerCozineDepreciation {
    public void main(String[] args){

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int item, year, cost, life, depreciationType, depreciationDuring, totalDepreciation, begPrice;
    //GEt all the needed data from the user
    System.out.println("What is the item");
    item=keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("What is the year of purchase?");
    year=keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("How much did it cost? (No decimals)");
    cost=keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("What is the item's estimated life span in years?");
    life=keyboard.nextInt();
    System.out.println("What is the method of depreciation?(1 for straight line or 2 for double decline)");
    depreciationType=keyboard.nextInt();

    //PRints the description and other info of the item
    System.out.println("Item:"+item);
    System.out.println("Year of Purchase: "+year);
    System.out.println("Cost of Purchase: "+cost);
    System.out.println("Estimated life: "+life);
    if(depreciationType ==1) {
        System.out.println("Straight line");
    }else{
        System.out.println("Double Decline");
    }

    System.out.println("Year\tValue at Beginning of Year\t\t"
                        +"Amount Depreciated During Year\t\tTotal Depreciated at End of Year");
    //Calculations of depreciations
    if(depreciationType==1) {
        while(year<=(year+life)){ //running only as many lines as wanted 

            year+=1;



            //System.out.format("%-8d" + "$%-39.2d"+ "$%39.2d" + "$%42.4d%n", year, cost, depreciationDuring, totalDepreciation);
        }



    }else {

    }

}


}
```

Comment: `year<=(year+life)`  will always be true unless life is negative. You don't need a while loop for this, really

Comment: Consider searching this site with Google for similar questions as this has been asked frequently, and you're surely to find many similar with code

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for decrementing the life value

```
while (life > 0) {  
    year++; life--; // as it gets more age, it has less life 
}
```

Otherwise written as

```
for ( ; life > 0; life--) {
    year++;
}
```

Based on the other conditions, you might want to try this instead, though

```
life -= depreciationType;
```